# PHP : Work with stdClass() for create a json

Tags: php, json, stdclass

My goal is to read a complex **sqlite** database with **php** , and create a **json** that represents the database according to certain rules

To do this I decided to use the **stdClass()** class

**problem** : when i call the **TEST() function** the block3 is not added

Test code (I tried to represent the situation at best, of course here I do not use database and foreach)

```
$OBJ = new stdClass();

$OBJ->block1 = array();

$OBJ->block1[0]["prop1"] = "test";
$OBJ->block1[0]["prop2"] = "test";
$OBJ->block1[0]["prop3"] = "test";
$OBJ->block1[0]["prop4"] = "test";



$OBJ->block2 = array();
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++) {
    $OBJ->block2[$i]["sxsxs"] = "test";
    $OBJ->block2[$i]["98u98u"] = "test";
    $OBJ->block2[$i]["jhjh"] = "test";
    $OBJ->block2[$i]["oiuoiu"] = "test";

    //this WORKS , but i want to do this in the TEST function
    //$OBJ->block2[$i]["block3"] = array();
    TEST($OBJ->block2[$i]);

}


function TEST($c){
    $c["block3"] = array();
}

echo json_encode($OBJ);
```

---

This is what i want , all is correct , but not the add of block3

```
{
    "block1": [
        {
            "prop1": "test",
            "prop2": "test",
            "prop3": "test",
            "prop4": "test"
        }
    ],
    "block2": [
        {
            "sxsxs": "test",
            "98u98u": "test",
            "jhjh": "test",
            "oiuoiu": "test"
            "block3" : []
        },
        {
            "sxsxs": "test",
            "98u98u": "test",
            "jhjh": "test",
            "oiuoiu": "test"
            "block3" : []
        },
        {
            "sxsxs": "test",
            "98u98u": "test",
            "jhjh": "test",
            "oiuoiu": "test"
            "block3" : []
        }
    ]
}
```

---

**I could not use the call to class TEST, but I would like to divide the various processes**

---

Comment: That's because `$OBJ->block2[$i]` is not an object, but an array.

Comment: if i tried this $OBJ->block2[0]["block3"] = array(); ,just out the for, the block is added correctly

Comment: $OBJ->block1 is an array. $OBJ->block1[$i] is NOT an array

Comment: I updated the question, any suggestions? thanks

Answer (score -1):

The variable that you send into TEST function is not an object. It's an array.

Do a var_dump on $c inside the TEST function and you will get:

array(4) {
  ["sxsxs"]=>
  string(4) "test"
  ["98u98u"]=>
  string(4) "test"
  ["jhjh"]=>
  string(4) "test"
  ["oiuoiu"]=>
  string(4) "test"
}

You can't add variables using -> operator to an array.
Perhaps this is what you tried to accomplish:

```
$OBJ = new stdClass();

$OBJ->block1 = array();

$OBJ->block1[0]["prop1"] = "test";
$OBJ->block1[0]["prop2"] = "test";
$OBJ->block1[0]["prop3"] = "test";
$OBJ->block1[0]["prop4"] = "test";



$OBJ->block2 = array();
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++) {
    $OBJ->block2[$i]["sxsxs"] = "test";
    $OBJ->block2[$i]["98u98u"] = "test";
    $OBJ->block2[$i]["jhjh"] = "test";
    $OBJ->block2[$i]["oiuoiu"] = "test";

    TEST($OBJ);

}


function TEST($c){
    $c->block3 = array();
}


echo json_encode($OBJ);
```

output:

{"block1":[{"prop1":"test","prop2":"test","prop3":"test","prop4":"test"}],"block2":[{"sxsxs":"test","98u98u":"test","jhjh":"test","oiuoiu":"test"},{"sxsxs":"test","98u98u":"test","jhjh":"test","oiuoiu":"test"},{"sxsxs":"test","98u98u":"test","jhjh":"test","oiuoiu":"test"}],"block3":[]}